# Can't make empty selection in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

I don't know how it happened, but all of a sudden in my table view I can't make an empty selection anymore. Like a table view row always has to be selected, and it can't be deselected by clicking somewhere else in the table view. I can select a different row, but I can't make an empty selection.

In the Interface Builder attributes for the table view empty selection is enabled, so I don't know where to look next. The one major change I made was that I installed OS X Snow Leopard. I'm not sure if this issue has something to do with that.

Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like for didSelectRowAtIndexPath?  Also, is this in the simulator or on the device?

Comment: Hi, I don't have that method implemented. And this is OS X development, not iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not allowed to say much more than this: It seems to be a problem with 10.6 specifically

Comment: Sorry to say this but then what do you expect by asking a question about an operating system that has not been released yet, and which you are under an NDA about.

Answer (score 2):

I struck this exact same issue (I am using XCode 4.2 but compiling against the 10.6sdk). NSOutlineView::deselectAll just was not deselecting things. I have a fairly complex NSOutlineView which exhibits the same behavior. I had a look on the apple developer forums and other places to try and work around this issue. However in the end working around this for me was very simple and I could just use:

```
- (void) myDeselectAll
{
   [self selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSet] byExtendingSelection:NO];
}
```

Comment: If you are supporting 10.6 you need to do this instead of deselectAll.  You'll want to download the 10.6sdk and set it as your base sdk in order to see this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it programmatically with the setter method `setAllowsEmptySelection:`.  Alternatively, try disabling empty selection in IB, saving, then enabling it, saving one more time.  That might fix it.

Also make sure that something in `tableView:shouldSelectRow:` isn't stopping you from it (provided you've implemented this delegate method).

Comment: I've tried both of those, including setting it programatically and the problem still persists. I don't have any delegate methods for the table view except for a few that are used for drag and drop.

Comment: Silly question, but you do have the outlet set, right? :)  Anyways, check the array controller's attributes, if you're using one (like Peter Hosey suggested).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but for those who need an answer to this: 
Use the interface builder and mark the array controller. remove checkmark "avoid empty selection". 
If not done so, create an outlet for the array controller. Here I have called it DocumentArrayController.

then to empty selection:

```
 [_DocumentArrayController removeSelectionIndexes:
      [_DocumentArrayController selectionIndexes]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your columns bound to an array controller? If so, check the controller's attributes.

Comment: Yeah, the array controller's "Avoid Empty Selection" attribute was checked, I unchecked it and then tried again but still doesn't work.